# Declaring ListView In Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am not getting any compilation error. But The problem is when i start the app it's not showing anything except a blank screen.
So I am going to provide the codes below.
package layout;

Fragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.buckydroid.sunshine.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class main extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ListView list = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast) ;


        String[] listviewforecast = {
                "Bucky - Great",
                "Marie - Shit",
                "Paul - kek"
        };
        List<String> listing= new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(listviewforecast)
        );
        ArrayAdapter arrayada = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview
        );
        list.setAdapter(arrayada);

return rootview;


    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event

}
```

And yes i added the fragment to activity_main.xml file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving any data to the `Adapter`.
In the constructor you should pass your `List<String>`:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayada = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(),
        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
        listing
);
```

You can also use `listviewforecast` if you want